# Spring Security oddity in <intercept-url> when specifying method

Tags: java, spring-security

I've been playing around with Spring Security a bit and noticed the following oddity.

When I specify the `<http>` block like this in my security context XML.

```
<http>
    <http-basic/>

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8181"/>
    </port-mappings>

    <intercept-url pattern="/url1**" access="ROLE_ROLE1" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/url2**" access="ROLE_ROLE2"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/url3**" access="ROLE_ROLE3" />
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</http>
```

All the urls seem to trigger a HTTP basic authentication pop up when I hit the various URLs with the browser.

This is good and what I expected, but when I add a method parameter to 1 of the intercept URLs like this:

```
<http>
    <http-basic/>

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8181"/>
    </port-mappings>

    <intercept-url pattern="/url1**" access="ROLE_ROLE1" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/url2**" access="ROLE_ROLE2" method="GET"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/url3**" access="ROLE_ROLE3" />
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</http>
```

The basic authentication is turned off for all the URLs except the one I've explicitly set the method on (`/url2`).

Is this how it's supposed to work, because it seems a little goofy to me.  Is this a bug?

Comment: I've tried it and works fine.

Comment: so when you go to url1, it asks you for your authentication info?  Not only do I not see this box, but it does not go through my custom authentication manager.  What version of spring security do you have?  I am using 3.0.0.M2.

Comment: I tested url3 because I didn't setup an https connector for url1. I used spring security 2.0.4 from spring-security-samples-tutorial-2.0.4.war.

Comment: I get the feeling that my request is not matching any of the intercept urls for some reason.  I'm guessing because I do not specifically list the GET method for url1, the request is falling through.  I was under the impression that if I don't list any method it should match them all (like it does in the first example). However, it does seem to match url1 at some point during the request because I am getting redirected to the https url (so the "requires-channel" is being invoked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I have tested **url1** with https and it works. I got redirected and then the login dialog showed up.
Setting logging level to DEBUG it prints:

```
DEBUG DefaultFilterInvocationDefinitionSource,http-8443-1:196 - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/url1/'; to: '/url1/'  
DEBUG DefaultFilterInvocationDefinitionSource,http-8443-1:224 - Candidate is: '/url1/'; pattern is /url2**; matched=false  
DEBUG DefaultFilterInvocationDefinitionSource,http-8443-1:224 - Candidate is: '/url1/'; pattern is /url1**; matched=true  
DEBUG AbstractSecurityInterceptor,http-8443-1:250 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /url1/; ConfigAttributes: [ROLE_USER]
DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext,http-8443-1:244 - Publishing event in context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@17af46e]: org.springframework.security.event.authorization.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /url1/]
DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter,http-8443-1:150 - Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point
```

This is the configuration:

```
<http>
  <http-basic/>
  <port-mappings>
     <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
  </port-mappings>
  <intercept-url pattern="/url1**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/url2**" access="ROLE_TELLER" method="GET"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/url3**" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR" />      
</http>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!  This *looks* like the same config I have.  The only think I can figure is that it's a new bug in 3.0.0.M2 which didn't exist in 2.0.4.

Comment: As you said it's a bug. I tested it with 3.0.0 M2. Also I found where the bug is so I reported it to their Jira: http://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1236